# Using \t in a regex does not seem to work with all tabs

Tags: regex, grep

Some lines of a file do not seem to match \t in a regex. Would anyone have an idea why ?

Let's take the example file that you can download from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt.

```
$ wget http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt
--2011-02-03 16:24:08--  http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt
Resolving download.geonames.org... 178.63.52.141
Connecting to download.geonames.org|178.63.52.141|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 31204 (30K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `countryInfo.txt'

100%[===================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 31,204      75.0K/s   in 0.4s    

2011-02-03 16:24:10 (75.0 KB/s) - `countryInfo.txt' saved [31204/31204]

$ cat countryInfo.txt | grep -E 'AD.AND'
AD  AND 200 AN  Andorra Andorra la Vella    468 84000   EU  .ad EUR Euro    376 AD###   ^(?:AD)*(\d{3})$    ca  3041565 ES,FR   
sdalouche@samxps:/tmp$ cat countryInfo.txt | grep -E 'AD\tAND'
(no result)

output of vi :set list
AD^IAND^I200^IAN^IAndorra^IAndorra la Vella^I468^I84000^IEU^I.ad^IEUR^IEuro^I376^IAD###^I^(?:AD)*(\d{3})$^Ica^I3041565^IES,FR^I$
```

Comment: Any reason not to use \s+ instead?

Comment: well, the file is tab separated, so if I match using \s, I will get different entries for Andorra la Vella, which is supposed to be only one field..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the `-P` option instead of `-E`:

```
cat countryInfo.txt | grep -P 'AD\tAND'
```

This will use Perl style regular expressions, which will catch the `\t`.

```
$ echo -e '-\t-' | grep -E '\t'
(no result)
$ echo -e '-\t-' | grep -P '\t'
-   -
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean standard regex do not support \t ?

Comment: @Sami Dalouche: what's your definition of "standard regex"?

Comment: @Bryan: Sami is probalby referring to POSIX

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation for grep I see no mention that `\t` represents tab. Remember, not all regular expression engines are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are not part of POSIX regular expressions (the standard for grep). But you can produce a literal tab character like this:

```
echo -ne "\\t"
```

So, grepping for a tab works like this:

```
grep "AD$(echo -ne "\\t")AND"
```

or

```
t=$(echo -ne "\\t")
grep "AD${t}AND"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a literal tab. While being in the terminal press CTRL+V and then press the TAB key. That will make a tab whitespace at the cursor point which can be used in your regular expression.

```
ls | grep -E "[0-9]<CTRL+V><TAB>]"
```

This will search for any number from 0 to 9 with a tab character just after it.